# Como mostrar los mensajes de validación en español primefaces JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jpa

Hola estoy trabajando con **JSF** y **primefaces** el problema que tengo es que los mensajes de validación me los muestra en **ingles (size must be between 1 and 50 )** cuando esta en producción, el servidor es un centos y en mi local si me muestra los mensajes en **español (el tamaño tiene que estar entre 1 y 50)**.

Cabe mencionar que la validación que muestra es por que en mi entidad el campo tiene un size maximo y minimo:

```
 @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "nombreCampo")
    private String nombreCampo;
```

y mi componente es el siguiente:

```
<p:inputText id="text" 
             value="#{controlador.entidad.campo}" 
             required="true" 
             requiredMessage="#{messages.campoRequerido}"    
             size="27"/>
<p:message for="text" />
```

Alguien conoce que propiedad poner para que aparesca en formato español parecido al **local = "es"**

Answer (score 0):

prime por defecto viene solo con soporte para ingles: si quieres traducir los mensajes a otro idioma debes agregarlo manualmente a travez de javascript así:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            PrimeFaces.locales['es'] = {
                closeText: 'Cerrar',
                prevText: 'Anterior',
                nextText: 'Siguiente',
                monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
                dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],
                dayNamesMin: ['D','L','M','X','J','V','S'],
                weekHeader: 'Semana',
                firstDay: 1,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: '',
                timeOnlyTitle: 'Sólo hora',
                timeText: 'Tiempo',
                hourText: 'Hora',
                minuteText: 'Minuto',
                secondText: 'Segundo',
                currentText: 'Fecha actual',
                ampm: false,
                month: 'Mes',
                week: 'Semana',
                day: 'Día',
                allDayText : 'Todo el día',
        messages: {
    'javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED': '{0}: Validation Error: Value is required.',
            'javax.faces.converter.IntegerConverter.INTEGER': '{2}: \'{0}\' must be a number consisting of one or more digits.',
    ...
        }
        };
</script>
```

El siguiente link te puede ayudar bastante: [Locale](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Locales)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes personalizar esos mensajes desde la definición de la columna en la entidad. En mi caso personalicé el mensaje de un campo de tipo BigDecimal para que sea mayor a cero:

```
@Column(name = "MONTO_DEVUELVE")
@DecimalMin(value = "0.01", message = "El valor debe ser mayor a 0")
private BigDecimal montoDevuelve;
```

Answer (score 0):

Es muy facil de solucionar, esto lo hace mediante un `FacessMessages` el cuál debe de ir en tu validación de tu controlador. Mira:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new 
FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "El nombre del campo 
no puede ir vacio!!!"));
```

En tu `xhtml` debes de poner esta etiqueta:

```
<p:messages id="mensaje" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" 
closable="true" globalOnly="true"/>
```

En **primefaces** hay varios tipos de mensajes te dejo el link para que lo puedas estudiar.

[PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml)